# How to make dunst show repeated notifications of the same program as one single notification

Tags: notifications, notify-send

here are my notifications and I would like each notification to replace the one before it

by the way I am using dunst for my notifications

[image]

Comment: which display manager is this / dbus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `dunstify` instead of `notify-send`, because first one allows you to use notification ID and replace older notifications with newer ones. Here is link to [info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dunst#Dunstify) about dunstify, and link to [example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dunst#Using_dunstify_as_volume/brightness_level_indicator) of creating volume level indicator.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in this github [comment](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst/issues/321#issuecomment-437693443): dunst now supports stack-tag feature. You simply need to assign custom tag to your notification like so:

```
notify-send --hint=string:x-dunst-stack-tag:test SUMMARY BODY
```

where `test` is an example of a custom tag.

Answer (score 1):

man dunst:

> ```
>    stack_duplicates (values: [true/false], default: true)
>        If set to true, duplicate notifications will be stacked together
>        instead of being displayed separately.
>
>        Two notifications are considered duplicate if the name of the
>        program that sent it, summary, body, icon and urgency are all
>        identical.
>
>    hide_duplicates_count (values: [true/false], default: false)
>        Hide the count of stacked duplicate notifications.
> ```

Comment: yes and I set it to true yet they are not merged !!

Comment: try newer version, i use 1.3.2.

Comment: I have the same version as you do,   **arch linux - i3wm **

Comment: I use icewm 1.4.3.0~pre-20181030 on debian sid. I've tested with pavucontrol volume up/down, and the notifications are in the same box. Fill a [bugreport](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst/issues) then..